# Abot C# multithreaded

Tags: c#, web-crawler, abot

Is it possible to call Abot Crawler multi-threaded? Have looked a code examples but did not find answer.
When I create 1 instance of Abot Crawler and call Crawl method in foreach statement only 1 fires completed event.

```
foreach(var pero in list)
{
      crawler.Crawl(pero.Url);
}
```

This does not work.Crawler_PageCrawlCompletedAsync is called only once.

Comment: Is this what you want : https://abotx.org/Learn/ParallelCrawlerEngine

Comment: This is used to crawl multiple sites. I need to crawl multiple urls on same site.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a foreach loop. Abot does multithreading in the background. You give it a url to crawl and it will spawn up to x number of concurrent http requests per single crawler object instance. This can be set by using the Abot2.Poco.CrawlConfiguration.MaxConcurrentThreads setting.

```
var config = new CrawlConfiguration
{
    MaxConcurrentThreads = 10
    MaxPagesToCrawl = 50, 
};
var crawler = new PoliteWebCrawler(config);

crawler.PageCrawlCompleted += PageCrawlCompleted;//Several events available...

var crawlResult = await crawler.CrawlAsync(new Uri("http://!!!!!!!!YOURSITEHERE!!!!!!!!!.com"));
```

Just be careful. It can request and process pages much faster than most sites can/will serve them. Its very easy to get your ip banned/blocked.